# __truediv__ method in a Fraction class

Tags: python

I have written a `Fraction` class and the `__truediv__` method to divide two fractions. But I don't know what to put into the `__truediv__` so that it prints out the division of two mentioned fractions.

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator = 0, denominator = 1):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return Fraction(other.denominator//self.numerator,
                        self.denominator * other.numerator)




 >>>fraction1 = Fraction(1, 2)
    fraction2 = Fraction(3, 4)
    fraction3 = fraction1 / fraction2
    print(fraction3)
```

Comment: Remember that `(a/b) / (c/d)` is the same as `(a/b) * (d/c)` which is just `ad / bc`.  Your answer will require multiplication, and then a gcd and two divisions to reduce the resulting fraction to lowest terms.

Comment: Are you aware of [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I think your math is a bit rusty, instead of:

```
return Fraction(other.denominator//self.numerator, self.denominator * other.numerator)
```

You should have:

```
return Fraction(other.denominator * self.numerator, self.denominator * other.numerator)
```